# Eclipse plugin: Using components of another perspective

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I already created a new Eclipse perspective, but I would like to know if it is possible to use the same elements and buttons (toolbar ones) that are in the C/C++ perspective?

Is there a way to use them in my own perspective?

Comment: There are several ways to do that. You could just simply put your common toolbar actions in the application's action bar advisor (i.e. in your core product plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Usually all plug-ins has a folder called `icons` in it. Look into this folder and copy the icons to your plug-in.

For C/C++ perspective icons look at all jars(inside `<eclipseInstallationLocation>\plugins` folder) containing the name 'cdt` copy all icon files from these jars to your plugin.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that he's looking also for the functionality behind those buttons and not just the icons.